# Properly Load Microsoft.ML model in Xamarin App?

Tags: machine-learning, xamarin, model, ml.net, machine-learning-model

I was learning a bit about how Machine Learning works and eventually built a small C# application because of a tutorial I was watching where a model determines what species of Bee a particular bee IS. It works well in the C# application, but I was also developing an app project that had picture taking capabilities in mind so I thought "No reason the model I saved in the first project can't work in the second, right?". Apparently there is a reason why it can't work because here is the necessary code to view in the app project:

```
MLContext m_mlObj;
DataViewSchema m_modelSchema;
ITransformer m_loadedTrainedModel;

var folderPath = DependencyService.Get<IFileSystem>().GetExternalStorage();
var fileDir = Path.Combine(folderPath, "trainedModel.zip");

bool testValue = File.Exists(fileDir);

if(testValue)
{
    Console.WriteLine("File in fact exists.");

    try
    {
         m_loadedTrainedModel = m_mlObj.Model.Load(fileDir, out m_modelSchema);
    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {
         Console.WriteLine("\n\n\nInner exception: " + e.InnerException);
    }
}

else
{
     Console.WriteLine("File does not exist");
}
```

I have a breakpoint on the "m_loadedTrainedModel = m_mlObj.Model.Load(fileDir, out m_modelSchema);" line of course and it always triggers an exception.

The exception states:

> ---> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type of field 'Microsoft.ML.Transforms.DnnRetrainTransformer:_tfInputShapes' (9) due to: Could not resolve type with token 01000060 from typeref (expected class 'Tensorflow.TensorShape' in assembly 'TensorFlow.NET, Version=0.20.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51') assembly:TensorFlow.NET, Version=0.20.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd5 1 type:Tensorflow.TensorShape member:(null)

What I THINK this means is it's checking for Tensorflow.TensorShape inside of the package TensorFlow.NET and isn't finding it. If that's the case, I believe I don't have the correct package installed so my Xamarin project will be able to load the model correctly, maybe? Or if not, then what may be the real underlying issue? The code seems straight forward so I'm a bit perplexed as to how this is failing.

If the solution is blatantly going over my head, my apologies and thank you to anyone who is willing to help.

Comment: Update: Just to see what I would GET, I got rid of the Tensorflow.NET (v0.60.2) package, I got THIS error:
Inner exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: tensorflow assembly:<unknown assembly> type:<unknown type> member:(null)" Is there a DLL I'm missing somewhere that is the underlying issue or should I just ignore this and continue worrying about my first question?

Comment: 1) which **specific** packages are you using?, 2) which platform are you testing with?

Comment: 1) I'm using a] Microsoft.ML b] Microsoft.ML.ImageAnalytics c] Microsoft.ML.Tensorflow d] Microsoft.ML.Vision e] NumSharp.Lite f] Syncfusion.Xamarin.SfImageEditor g] TensorFlow.NET h] Xam.Plugin.Media i] Xamarin.Essentials j] Xamarin.Forms

2) If I understand your question, I'm developing this app on the android platform but I'm attempting to load the model in the shared project. Hope that's not an issue as well

Comment: a cursory search seems to indicate that you should be using TensorFlow Lite for mobile devices.  I don't see a lot of references to using the full TensorFlow library on Xamarin.  I may be wrong, this is not something I've ever done myself

Comment: Hmm, so it could be possible that my mistake was actually not using the FULL TensorFlow library on Xamarin? Interesting. Well if I WAS using TensorFlow Lite, I don't think it was blatant that that was the package I installed. I'll check again and see.

Comment: Excuse me, I misread, you said I SHOULD be using TensorFlow lite for mobile devices

Answer (score 1):

When working with ML.NET on ARM, TensorFlow is one of the limitations at the time of this writing.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/ml-net-june-updates-model-builder/#ml-net-on-arm

What you might want to consider in the meantime is deploying your model as a Web API and making requests to that API from your mobile app.

https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/machine-learning/how-to-guides/serve-model-web-api-ml-net

Comment: Thank you for the response, I'll look into this after I give the other response Jason gave which was about TensorFlow Lite! Also I'm not quite familiar with ARM right now, but the first link states "which enables platform support for mobile and embedded devices as well as ARM-based servers." so I'm sure I can get it working with Xamarin.

Comment: You can also consider using ONNX serialization, you can convert your TF model to ONNX.